# Jquery, send default value with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a select box. The selected option is sent with ajax to a server side script. This works well.

**the select box**

```
<select id="main_select">
    <option selected="selected">50</option>
       <option value="40">40</option>
       <option value="30">30</option>
       <!-- other options -->
</select>
```

How can I extend the .change function that the default value `<option selected="selected">50</option>`is automatically send with the page load.

**script:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#main_select').change(function () {
           $.ajax({
               url: "itemscript.php",
               type: "post",
               data: {option: $(this).find("option:selected").val()},
               success: function(data){

                   $("#details").html(data);
               }
           });
       });
});
```

Comment: Do you mean: "How can I have the selection that fired the `.change` function be the selected option when the page reloads?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just trigger the `change` event when the page is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#main_select').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "itemscript.php",
      type: "post",
      data: {
        option: $(this).val()
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#details").html(data);
      }
    });
  }).change();
});
```

Also, you can use `$(this).val()`, that gets the value of the selected option.

Answer (score 0):

Why not extract the functionality to a seperate function? This helps to avoid hacks like triggering a `change` manually - if you had multiple listeners for such a change event, all would fire, and this might not be what you expect to happen ;)

```js
function getData(select) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "itemscript.php",
        type: "post",
        data: { option: $(select).find("option:selected").val() },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#details").html(data);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    getData($('#main_select'));
    $('#main_select').change(getData);
});
```